# awk and log2 divisions

Tags: awk

I have a tab delimited file that looks something like this:

```
foo 0 4

boo 3 2

blah 4 0

flah 1 1
```

I am trying to calculate log2 for between the two columns for each row. my problem is with the division by zero
What I have tried is this:

```
cat file.txt | awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, log($3/$2)log(2)}'
```

when there is a zero as the denominator, the awk will crash. What I would want to do is some sort of conditional statement that would print an "inf" as the result when the denominator is equal to 0.

I am really not sure how to go about this?
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Add a condition before evaluating: `cat file.txt | awk -v OFS='\t' '{if($2!=0) print $1, log($3/$2)log(2)}' `

Comment: You have to divide by log10(2) rather than multiply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement that as follows (with a few additional tweaks):

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {if ($2==0) {print $1, "inf"} else {print $1, log($3/$2)log(2)}} file.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `if ($2==0) {print $1, "inf"} else {...}` - First check to see if the 2nd field (`$2`) is zero. If so, print `$1` and `inf` and move on to the next line; otherwise proceed as usual.
- `BEGIN{OFS="\t"}` - Set `OFS` inside the awk script; mostly a preference thing.
- `... file.txt` - awk can read from files when you specify it as an argument; this saves the use of a cat process. (See [UUCA](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html))

Comment: This excellent. It works! It was the else command that got me...Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'\t' '{print $1,($2 ? log($3/$2)log(2) : "inf")}' file.txt
```